# Is the Order of Array Element Default-Initialization Defined?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer, default-initialization

When an array is default initialized,
is the order in which it's elements are default initialized defined by the C++ standard?

To give an example, is the following C++ program guaranteed do print strictly ascending memory addresses?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Foo{
    Foo() {
        std::cout << this << std::endl;
    }
};
int main() {
    delete[] new Foo[10];
    return 0;
}
```

I found the following in the Standard under 9.4.1 Initializers, General:

> 7 To default-initialize an object of type T means: (...)
>
> (7.2)— If T is an array type, each element is default-initialized.

Am I correct in assuming that this means that it's unspecified,
or is this clarified somewhere else in the document?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65282569/7204912) claims that It's defined (under (a)), but (afaict) does not provide any evidence for that.

Note that I'm not trying to refer to the array itself before it is initialized ([Can a (C/C++) array initialization reference itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467868/can-a-c-c-array-initialization-reference-itself)), but simply care about observable side effects of the initialization order.

Comment: Incidentally, the output in the code in the question doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: § 9.4.17.5 specifies *how* to initialize arrays, but makes no mention of order

Comment: afaik when the elements are initialized in order it is not guaranteed to get strictly increasing memory addresses printed.  `<` is unspecified for pointers, so "strictly increasing" isnt well defined. (I suppose thats not the actual point of the question, but you could use a static `int` counter as well to assert the order of initialization)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: Since the elements are part of an array, the < operator is well defined on pointers to it's members: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44397784/is-operator-less-than-on-pointers-consistent

Comment: @ChrisB I wasnt aware. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest draft (N4917) has this to say under 9.4.2 Aggregates, item 7 ([dcl.init.aggr]):

> The initializations of the elements of the aggregate are evaluated in the element order. That is, all value
> computations and side effects associated with a given element are sequenced before those of any element that
> follows it in order.

So you can depend on the order.

Comment: Just a side-note that this wording isn't particularly new either. It goes back to at least N4800, from January of 2019 (the oldest draft I have handy).

Comment: I was certain that the rule has been this way since forever, as it is the simplest and most efficient implementation (at least I think it is), but C++11 only mentions the order when there is an initializer, and C++03 has nothing to say about the order at all. (Or it's hidden in a non-obvious place in those two.)

Comment: C++98 [class.init]/3: "When an array of class objects is initialized (either explicitly or implicitly), the constructor shall be called for each element of the array, following the subscript order; see 8.3.4. [*Note:* destructors for the array elements are called in reverse order of their construction. ]"

Comment: @BrianBi Oh, it was in the other obvious place...